# Mandarin equivalent of "stir crazy"

Tags: expressions

Is there a concise way to express "stir crazy" in Mandarin, or is a long explanation needed?

Comment: I am not familiar with this phrase. After searching it on the internet, I find a phrase "go stir crazy", which means "to be upset from staying in a place for a long time". Is this yours?

Comment: Yes, this is what I'm looking for. From Wikipedia: "..anyone who becomes restless or anxious from feeling trapped and even somewhat claustrophobic in an environment, usually a confined space, perceived to be more static and unengaging than can any longer continue to hold interest, meaning, and value to and for them"

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about this phrase very much, does it mean "drive somebody crazy"? If so, I think this one is ok:

> 逼疯了
>   <sub>bī fēng le</sub>

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are talking about claustrophobia? "幽闭恐惧症" or "闭室恐幽症", but can not think of any slang to describe it? Maybe "恐幽症"?

There is a wikipedia page for it titled "[幽闭恐惧症](http://zh.wikipedia.org/zh/%E5%B9%BD%E9%97%AD%E6%81%90%E6%83%A7%E7%97%87)".

Comment: I'm not sure is "claustrophobic" is an appropriate translation, nor do I think there is a Mandarin equivalent to to "stir crazy". Maybe `發瘋了` (become/go crazy/mad) or `閉疯了` (go crazy due to being shut in/incarcerated) would be more appropriate.